# Spring security custom html login page not rendered

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i have followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoTohM2jYhs) for all configurations to set link up my custom html page for login. However, when i access localhost/login, i am faced with error status 500.

I am unable to render a simple html page when I access localhost:8080/login.

1. Are there extra configurations needed?
2. Should the html page be located at templates folder? How does the application know it should render "login.html" ?
3. Is my controller being recognised?

config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll();

    }

}
```

controller.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

replacing "login" above with below also shows error.

```html
<h1> Login page <h1>
```

dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

login.html is located in templates.
error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Comment: Will you please share your code? While I appreciate the video link, it's time-consuming for readers to process.

Comment: I have added the code that was used.

Comment: The code looks fine so far. Would you be able to share your code sample via GitHub?

Comment: I have managed to resolve this issue myself and left it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this. The main issue was because my artefactID was also named login. This resulted in all other context of "login", including "login.html" to be voided. I modified my controller to below and changing my html file to login2.html it worked.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login2() {
        return "login2";
    }
}
```