# Spring does not render custom error page for uncaught exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to fix our spring web app which doesn't show uncaught exception errors properly. (Hasn't done for a couple of years) It simply shows the html code, instead of rendering it. Other errors such as ResourceNotFound are displaying their custom error page nicely.

From my understanding it goes like this, in the WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>
```

that thing routes it to controller, UncaughtExceptionViewController:

```
@RequestMapping("/uncaughtException")
@Controller
public class UncaughtExceptionViewController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String uncaughtException() {
        return "uncaughtException";
    }
}
```

Which then goes to corresponding views.xml:

```
<definition extends="basePage" name="uncaughtException">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/uncaughtExceptionWorkaround.jspx"/>
</definition>
```

I've messed around with both basePage and uncaughtExceptionWorkaround.jspx (bascially reducing them to a clean `<html><body></body></html>`), I do not think the error is in them. Their code-contents are displayed on the screen.

It does hit breakpoints in the controllers. Also for example our ResourceNotFoundViewController works perfectly, and it is very similar:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

'

```
@RequestMapping("/resourceNotFound")
@Controller
public class ResourceNotFoundViewController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String resourceNotFound() {
        return "resourceNotFound";
    }
}
```

---

I've tried adding stuff to applicationContext-security.xml

```
<intercept-url pattern="/uncaughtException" access="permitAll"/>
```

and modifying the controller annotation like:

```
 @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
```

And I also tried to change the location to "/uncaughtException2" and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015102/spring-security-custom-html-login-page-not-rendered) but the problem persists.

One difference between the uncaught exception and the things that work is this bean in webmvc-config.xml:

```
<bean class="se.justLog.server.spring.LoggingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".ResetPasswordException">resetpasswordfailed</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried adding the `.RuntimeException` to see if it made any difference but no.

Interestingly! if I remove the entire LoggingExceptionResolver (which is a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver) bean, then the HTML renders, but the exception-variable in the .jspx page becomes empty, so it does not show the error.

Awefully interesting this, do you have any idea? (I'm not a Spring guru, is there some step I've missed investigating?)

Edit: Spring doesn't add the Content-type: text/html header, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Spring’s `@ControllerAdvice`

The `@ControllerAdvice` annotation  allows you to handle exceptions across the whole application, not just to an individual controller. You can think of it as an interceptor of exceptions thrown by methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. It's a great way to handle exceptions and errors.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView uncaughtException(Exception e) {
        
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("uncaughtException");
        mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());

        return mav;
    }
}
```

uncaughtException.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ops! Something went wrong</h1>
    <b>${name}</b>:  ${message}
</body>
</html>
```